# How to stop uWSGI in emperor mode?

Tags: nginx, webserver, uwsgi

I am using the following command to start uwsgi for my website. How do I stop it?

```
sudo ln -s /var/www/$project_name/$project_name/$project_name.uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/vassals/
sudo uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data &
```

Comment: Try this out: http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2012-February/003560.html